# ag-grid Pie Chart make some items invisible initially

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, pie-chart

I am using ag-grid to create Pie Charts in Angular.  I am following this URL for API documentation : https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-charts/pie-series/

I want to hide some items initially.  (*I know I can hide the entire series using "visible: false"*).  I only want some items to be hidden initially.  The user can then click on the **legend** of the hiden item and toggle the item ON if needed.

For e.g. in the following data, I want Android and iOS to be invisible initially

```
export function getData() {
    return [
        { label: 'Android', value: 56.9 },
        { label: 'iOS', value: 22.5 },
        { label: 'BlackBerry', value: 6.8 },
        { label: 'Symbian', value: 8.5 },
        { label: 'Bada', value: 2.6 },
        { label: 'Windows', value: 1.9 },
    ];
}
```

My use case is as follows. We have 8 items/sectors in the chart.  We have millions of count in the 3 success states, and there are only few counts in the other 5 error/warning state.  The chart looks mostly green with just thin lines for error states.  Most users are only interested in errors and they have to manually turn off success states by clicking on the legend to only focus on error states.  So, I want to turn off the success states initially, and if any one wants to see the success states they can click on the legend and turn them on.

I tried using multiple series, listeners, etc. But the API documentation does not clearly state how to set the initial state of the item in the legend.